# ggmap error (Error in as.vector(y) : attempt to apply non-function)

Tags: r, ggmap

I'm doing relatively simple things with ggmap and am confused because code that runs fine on my mac does not run on my PC.

I run this code:

```
library(ggmap)

map <- get_map(location = c(-122.175, 37.45635),
               maptype = "terrain",
               source = "google",
               crop = FALSE,
               zoom = 7)
 ggmap(map)
```

, which runs fine on my mac, but throws this error on my PC:

Error in as.vector(y) : attempt to apply non-function

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Unable to reproduce, works fine on my Windows machine. Try restarting R, or reinstalling the package.

Comment: Right, it works fine on my mac as well + I of course already tried restarting R and restarting my computer. That's why I posted the question - to see if anyone might have any ideas on what could be going wrong on a PC. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3):

It is no longer necessary to uninstall ggplot2 to fix this error. I was able to update ggplot by running install.packages("ggplot2"), then reinstall ggmap. This solved the problem for me.

Comment: I confirm that updating from ggplot2 2.1.0 to ggplot2 2.2.1 also worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I faced that problem after installing R and RStudio last week. Restarting RStudio or R session, or reinstalling ggmap package didn't work for me. I'd just fixed it with these steps:

- Uninstall R and RStudio
- Delete old folders related to R and RStudio in Program Files (I had things like older versions of R).
- Delete Windows temporary files (just in case)
- Install R and RStudio again
- Install ggmap package

Comment: Thank you! This is what ended up working on my work PC. Whew :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this problem comes from the last update of ggplot2. See the following links:

- https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS.md#extensions
- [ggmap Error: GeomRasterAnn was built with an incompatible version of ggproto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40642850/ggmap-error-geomrasterann-was-built-with-an-incompatible-version-of-ggproto/40651687#40651687)

You could try to install an older version of ggplot (see below) or try to reinstall the packages like suggested in the link above.

```
    library(devtools)
    install_version("ggplot2", version = "2.1.0", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

Comment: Yes, I ended up then having this same trouble on my mac and this solution also worked for me -- thank you! (But also a bummer that I can't also utilize the new ggplot2 features - oh welll - this is what iterations are for I suppose!)

Comment: My experience seems to be the opposite (in Windows with RStudio): I had this error with ggplot2 2.1.0 and solved it by upgrading to ggplot2 2.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to Unistall R. Just erase ALL folders related to ggplot2, and reinstall the ggmap with all dependencies.