# Error when trying to use ggmap::get_map ( JPEG decompression error: Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x89 0x50)

Tags: r, jpeg, ggmap

I am trying to set up a map from ggmap.I have borrowed this line from another script but it is not working for me. I want to specify the boundary of the map.

```
myLocation <- c( -133.50734,   26.07781,  -60.49268,   47.77387)
myMap <- ggmap::get_map(location=myLocation, source="stamen", maptype="terrain", crop=TRUE)
```

The map should show the US boundary, but it throws the following error when trying to run it:

```
Map from URL : http://tile.stamen.com/terrain/5/4/11.jpg
Error in readJPEG(tmp) :
 JPEG decompression error: Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x89 0x50
```

Any comment on how to fix the issue?

Comment: I get no error. I have version 2.7 installed, and since the repo version is behind this, I suspect it was because someone else reported an error with the earlier version and it was fixed. Probably available at github.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40642850/ggmap-error-geomrasterann-was-built-with-an-incompatible-version-of-ggproto/40644348#40644348

Comment: A JPEG stream starts with FFD8, so somewhere it is getting something else.

Comment: I got the answer. Yes the version I had installed was behind the change in the stamen. Thanks, for the answer.