# Coefplot fatal plotting error ggproto [R]

Tags: r, ggplot2, coefplot

I recently installed the coefplot package to plot the confidence intervals for a couple multivariate regressions.

However, I am getting a fatal error. I followed all of the steps listed by @jashu in 
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40642850/ggmap-error-geomrasterann-was-built-with-an-incompatible-version-of-ggproto) and restarted R, but it did not remedy my issue.

My code:

```
coefplot:::buildModelCI(fit) #This works 
coefplot(fit) #This causes error and does not plot
```

My Error:

```
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: xmin, xmax
Error: PositionDodgeV was built with an incompatible version of ggproto.
Please reinstall the package that provides this extension.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
devtools::install_github("jaredlander/coefplot")
```

It seems like jaredlander recently updated coefplot, which was causing the error.