# R plotROC package failing related to ggproto

Tags: r, ggplot2, package, ggproto

Running

```
install.packages("ggplot2", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")
install.packages("plotROC", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")
library(plotROC)
plotROC::geom_roc()
```

in R on my mac leads to

```
> plotROC::geom_roc()
Error: GeomRoc was built with an incompatible version of ggproto.
Please reinstall the package that provides this extension.
```

I've seen a few other SO posts related to "ggproto" but none of the suggestions has worked for me and I've kind of lost track of what exactly I tried so far.

Is `plotROC` necessarily the "package that provides this [ggproto] extension"?  If so, what else could I try other than re-install as shown above?  If not, how could I identify the package that needs to be updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling around suggests that install the dev versions might help:

```
devtools::install_github("hadley/ggplot2")
devtools::install_github("sachsmc/plotROC")
```

See [this related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40642850/ggmap-error-geomrasterann-was-built-with-an-incompatible-version-of-ggproto).